# Calculate the difference in two wind directions in python

Tags: python, numpy, math

How can I calculate the difference (WD_Bias) in two wind directions (in degrees) in python so that the results range from -180 to 180? Here is the code I have so far? Does this seem to do what I want or am I missing something else?

```
WD_Bias = WD_model - WD_obs

WD_Bias[WD_Bias>180.]=360.-WD_Bias[WD_Bias>180.]
WD_Bias[WD_Bias<-180.]=WD_Bias[WD_Bias<-180.]+360.
```

Comment: Velocity is a vector quantity.  I'd use vectors to find the resultant of two wind directions.

Answer (score 3):

If the wind directions that you are subtracting are the same magnitude, take the difference and use modulo arithmetic to get your answer between -180 and +180.

If they are different magnitudes, represent those as vectors (real+image works) then use inverse tangent to find the vector difference angle. Or use np.angle. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html

Comment: What `the same magnitude` are you talking about? Wind directions given in degrees are scalars. They (directions) might be considered as (unit) vectors to apply atan2 approach, but `different magnitudes` is nonsense here.

Comment: Wind velocity is a vector with a magnitude (speed) and direction (angle) component.

Comment: Difference of wind directions doesn't depend on magnitudes

Answer (score 2):

If you want errors ranging from 0 to 180 you can use the following function :

```
import numpy as np

def wdir_diff(wd1,wd2):
    diff1 = (wd1 - wd2)% 360
    diff2 = (wd2 - wd1)% 360
    res = np.minimum([diff1,diff2])
    return res
```

The following lines should provide insurance that the function produce the expected behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w1 = np.arange(0,360,5)
w2 = np.arange(0,360,5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(w1,w2)
Z = wdir_diff(X,Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
im= ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap="jet")
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think that should be: `res = np.minimum(diff1, diff2)`